# Windows create dynamic amount of links

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In my application i'm going to have a list of links I would like the user to be able to click on and will take them to a certain website. The problem is, first, it's possible there is going to be alot of links, second, there is a dynamic amount of links, and the amount changes.

One idea that came to mind was to somehow create a bunch of `STATIC` windows with `SS_NOTIFY`, but I would be creating and destroying windows often, and performance is a bit of a concern in this project. And keeping track of how many windows I have, and which one was clicked on wouldn't be easy.

So i'm looking for a easier way, or at least better way, to implement this.

I should also note i'm using C, and the Windows API.

Comment: You may find it easier to use a listview control with the LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE and either the LVS_EX_UNDERLINEHOT or LVS_EX_UNDERLINECOLD extended style, depending on what underlining style you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to worry about performance. On any machine from the past 10 years you will have no performance issues with filling a screen with windowed controls.

As for the control to use, I think [SysLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760706%28VS.85%29.aspx) sounds like the most appropriate choice.

If you are looking for easier ways to manage dynamic GUIs then you may want to contemplate a higher level framework. Programming the raw Windows API from C is pretty labour intensive.